# How do i set up an OR or || when using a ?: conditional statemetn

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, conditional-statements

I have the below code which works perfectly.  When the title is JohnPage, it does not display in the li.

```
<?php foreach($this->pages AS $page) { ?>
<li <?php echo $page['title'] == ('JohnPage') ? 'style="display:none";' : ''; ?>>
    <a<?php echo ($page['active']?' class="active"':'');?> href="<?php echo $page['href'];?>"><?php echo $page['title'];?></a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

However, I want to say: if the title is either JohnPage or MyPage, do not display in the li.  I tried the following:

```
<li <?php echo $page['title'] == ('JohnPage' OR 'MyPage') ? 'style="display:none";' : ''; ?>>

<li <?php echo $page['title'] == ('JohnPage' || 'MyPage') ? 'style="display:none";' : ''; ?>>
```

Neither works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: ($page['title'] == 'JohnPage' || $page['title'] ==  'MyPage')

Comment: Perfect, e4c5.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your conditional statements there. Try it this way.

```
<?php
foreach($this->pages AS $page) { ?>
<li <?php if($page['title'] == 'JohnPage' || $page['title'] == 'MyPage') { ?>style="display:none<?php } ?>">
<a <?php echo ($page['active']?' class="active"':'') ?> href="<?php echo $page['href'] ?>"><?php echo $page['title'] ?></a>
</li>
<?php 
} // end foreach
?>
```